# Monotone likelihood ratio of a family of densities with convexity property

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

(Asking again in a new question because the [previous version](https://mathoverflow.net/q/452519/36721) had insufficient conditions, as pointed out in the [answer there](https://mathoverflow.net/a/452659/36721).)

Define the densities:

$$p(\phi;\theta,r) = \Big(f\big(r\cos(\phi-\theta)\big) - f\big(r\cos(\phi+\theta)\big)\Big)\hspace{0.5pt} \frac{\sin(2\phi)}{\sin(2\theta)}, \quad 0 \le \phi,\theta\le \pi/2,\,r>0$$

where $f(x)=g(x^2)$, and the following hold: $g$ is twice-differentiable, increasing, and convex or concave on $(0,\infty)$, $g''(x)$ is non-decreasing on $(0,\infty)$, and $f'(0^+) < \infty$. Remarkably, the area of these densities is independent of $\theta$ whenever $g$ is increasing and concave or convex (without requiring the monotonicity of $g''(x)$), which can be shown using an integral representation. For $f(x)=|x|$, we have $\int_0^{\pi/2} p(\phi;\theta,r)d\phi=\frac{2}{3}r$.

Show that for all $r$, $p(\phi;\theta,r)$ has a monotone likelihood ratio (decreasing for concave $g$, increasing for convex $g$). I.e., for $0\le\theta_1 < \theta_2\le\pi/2$:

$$ h(\phi) = \frac{f\big(r\cos(\phi-\theta_2)\big) - f\big(r\cos(\phi+\theta_2)\big)}{f\big(r\cos(\phi-\theta_1)\big) - f\big(r\cos(\phi+\theta_1)\big)}$$

is monotonic on $[0,\pi/2]$.

Examples of functions are $f(x) = |x|^p$, $1\le p<2$, or for $p>2$. (For $p=2$, $p(\phi;\theta) = \sin^2(2\phi)$.) And the function $f(x) = \log( \cosh(x))$, which is concave in $x^2$, i.e. $g(x) = \log(\cosh(\sqrt{x}))$ is concave on $[0,\infty)$, and twice differentiable at $x=0$, unlike $|x|^p$, $p<2$.

An answer showing the this holds for either convex or concave $g$ is acceptable. This question can be considered as only asking for one of them.

This result is important to prove uniqueness of stable optima in the unmixing and deconvolution of linear mixtures of independent random variables with strongly sub- and super-gaussian densities, using the Karlin-Rubin theorem. The result can be proved for $f(x)=x^4$ by simplifying the derivative expression. This corresponds to using kurtosis as the the cost function, and the uniqueness result is already known in this case. For $f(x) = |x|$, the likelihood ratio is non-increasing, constant around $\phi=0$ and $\phi=\pi/2$.

Comment: What do you mean by"these densities indeed have the same measure for all $\theta$ whenever $g$ is concave or convex", and how to prove that?

Comment: I mean he integral over $\phi$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$ is independent of $\theta$, just a constant function of $f$ and $r$. This can be shown by writing these functions as scale mixtures of $1-(1-x^2)_+$ or $(x^2-1)_+$ with Stieltjes measure $-f'(x)/x$ or $f'(x)/x$. So the densities can be written as a sum of piecewise kernels, which depend on the $\theta$ and $r$, but somehow each $\theta$ and $r$ variant integrates to the same function of $r$ independent of $\theta$.

Comment: The stronger functions here can be written as scale mixtures of $1-(1-x^2)^2_+$ or $(x^2-1)^2_+$ with Stieltjes measure $f''(x)$.

Comment: I think that showing the MLRP for these piecewise kernels over the common non-zero support will show that they satisfy the MLRP, and that then the sum also satisfies the MLRP.

Comment: The equal area for all $\theta$ doesn't actually matter as any normalizing factor becomes a constant in the likelihood ratio. It's just interesting and unexpected.

Comment: Being able to calculate the function of $r$ however, and show that the resulting function also satisfies a scale MLRP, allows the proof that the overall expected function, which is a derivative, still has only one zero, and thus the function has one maximum. The $r$ function was the subject of the other question you answered.

Comment: Actually for the "stronger" functions the Stieltjes measure is $g''(x^2)$ not $f''(x)$.

Comment: As in your previous post, there are two questions in this post as well. These two questions may be related but, looking at the previous post, they may require different treatments. According to [MathOverflow guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-answer), users should avoid answering multiple questions in one post. So, can you edit your post so as to retain just one question there?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I edited to specify that I am only asking for one of them. I'd prefer to keep all the information in the question since it may help with the solution.

Comment: What if this is **dis**proved in one of the two cases?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I will accept a counterexample to either case.

Comment: As I imagine the combinatorial and tedious proof going, it might require that the $g^{(4)}(x)$ be univalent on $(0,\infty)$ to guarantee that the last of the three transformations has the MLRP. So perhaps a counter-example could be found.

Comment: Classes of functions, analogous to multiply montone and (multiply) absolutely monotone functions can be defined, where the function has $n$ positive derivatives, or is concave, with $n$ alternating sign derivatives, basically $n$-times Bernstein. The functions described here would be 3-times absolutely monotonic, or Bernstein, or possibly 4-times, in $x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$The "convex" part of this conjecture is not true in general.

Indeed, suppose it is true. Then (letting $x:=\phi$, $t:=\theta_1$, and $\theta_2\downarrow\theta_1=t$) we see that for any strictly increasing convex smooth function $g$ with $g'''\ge0$ and all $x$ and $t$ in $(0,\pi/2)$ we would have $h_2(g;x,t):=\partial_x\partial_t\,\ln(g(\cos^2(x-t))-g(\cos^2(x+t))\ge0$. (Note that for all $x$ and $t$ in $(0,\pi/2)$ we have $\cos^2(x-t)-\cos^2(x+t)=\sin2x\,\sin2t>0$, so that $h_2(g;x,t)$ is well defined.)
For $c$ and $c_*$ in $[0,\infty)$ and real $\ep>0$, let
$g(c):=g_{c_*,\ep}(c):=(\sqrt{(c-c_*)^2+\ep^2}+c-c_*)^2$.

Then the function $g$ is strictly increasing, convex, and smooth on $\mathbb R$, and $g'''>0$. However, $h_2(g;x,t)=-461586.955\ldots\not\ge0$ if $c_*=\frac{526}{1000}$, $\ep=\frac1{1000}$, $x=\frac{812}{1000}$, and $t=\frac{157}{100}$. So, the "convex" part of your conjecture is not true in general. $\quad\Box$

Comment: It appears that conditions should be imposed on the derivatives of $g$ of all orders.